# How to print colored text in .txt format

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I am using python 3.5version. I need to print hello statement in colored format in a file of .txt format.(windows platform) Is there any way to do that. I have tried colorama but could not print colored text in .txt file. 
Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Texts in txt format can not have colors, only plain text is saved, not rich text

Comment: Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Cant we make letters bold instead of changing color?

Comment: You have to save it in another format, for example HTML supports rich text

Comment: Text editors may have the ability to filter the values and give you some characteristics.

Comment: Thank you. But evenafter changing the format in html how could i make the letters coloured??

Comment: I recommend you read about rich text and HTML format

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will look into those topics

Comment: An alternative to HTML/RTF is to embed ANSI (VT100) escape sequences in the text, which are supported by most terminals. In Windows 10 even the [console supports VT100](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt638032) escape sequences. Try `os.system('echo \x1b[31mred foreground'); os.system('echo \x1b[0mdefault colors')`.

Answer (score 1):

The .txt format itself has no fonts/sizes/colors but you can use .rtf and if you are looking into printing colored text in console you can use ansi colors:

Regular colors:

```
ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
```

Background colors:

```
ANSI_BLACK_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[40m";
ANSI_RED_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[41m";
ANSI_GREEN_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[42m";
ANSI_YELLOW_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[43m";
ANSI_BLUE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[44m";
ANSI_PURPLE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[45m";
ANSI_CYAN_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[46m";
ANSI_WHITE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[47m";
```

These were made in Java but they should work just fine in Python
Also, this could just be my mistake but if i'm not mistaken command prompt don't allow for ansi colors but linux does just fine